# Swift: call overloaded method with ambiguous return type

Tags: swift, overloading, overload-resolution

Suppose I have the following code:

```
    public class A {}
    public class B : A {}
    public class Foo {
        public func bar() -> A {
            print("secret hidden method")
            return A()
        }

        public func bar() -> B {
            print("easily accessible method")
            return B()
        }
    }
```

The problem is try to call them leads to ambiguity.  You can call `bar() -> B` with `Foo().bar() as B`, but all of `Foo().bar()`, `Foo().bar() as A`, and `let a: A = Foo().bar()` yield an `Ambiguous use of 'bar()'` compiler error.

Bottom line: **How do I call `bar() -> A`?**  Is there some tricky syntax for it?  Is reflection necessary?  Is reflection *sufficient*?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler needs to be able to determine which variation of `bar()` you want to execute. You can be explicit about the type of `func` you want to execute, and take advantage of currying to access the correct implementation for a given instance.

```swift
let foo = Foo()
let a: ()->A = Foo.bar(foo)
let b: ()->B = Foo.bar(foo)
a()
b()
```

The above code will print:

```
secret hidden method
easily accessible method
```

Comment: Whaaaat, perfect!  New secret voodoo to solve my problems!  :P  Thanks!